# Varargs methods and primitive types

Tags: java, variadic-functions

In *Effective Java* J. Bloch mentioned that it was not safe to use varargs method with primitive types. Percisely, `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4)` had return type `List<int[]>` and it sounds quite reasonble. Now I tried to reproduce this behaviour myself and couldn't:

[image]

My question is why is the type deduced to `List<Integer>` but not to `List<int[]>` as he stated? Does it mean, that in Java 8 the problem about varargs is not relevant anymore and we can safely use them anywhere we want if we don't care about performance too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author most probably meant that you can't pass array of primitive type elements and expect it to be boxed like

```
int[] intArray = {1,2,3};
Arrays.asList(intArray);
```

which will return `List<int[]>` not `List<Integer>` since there is no autoboxing of arrays like `int[]->Integer[]` so only possible type which can be used by `T...` vararg is `int[]` since generic type `T` can't represent primitive type.

---

Other possible problem is that you are reading first edition of book (released in 2001) but autoboxing was added in Java 1.5 (Java 5.0) which was released in 2004.

Comment: But varargs was added in Java 1.5 too, so if the book mentions varargs it must be Java 5+.