# Can you check if an array of char contains a specific char value by converting as list?

Tags: java, arraylist, char

I am trying to check "using"the list contains () method to check for a character present in the array. The code seems to run but returns false.why is that?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class charcontain
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char arr[]={'2','a','g','4'};

        System.out.println("4 in arr : "+ Arrays.asList(arr).contains('4'));
    }
}
```

4 in arr : false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should). See also: [Varargs methods and primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098205/varargs-methods-and-primitive-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check what `Arrays.asList()` returns to you.

It returns you `List<char[]>` instead of `List<Character>` because char is primitive. Try using `Character[]` like the following:

```
    Character arr[] = {'2', 'a', 'g', '4'};
    List<Character> characters = Arrays.asList(arr);
    System.out.println("4 in arr : "+ characters.contains('4'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.asList(arr)
```

is not a `List<Character>`, it's a `List<char[]>`, with one element - the `char[]`. A `List<char[]>` doesn't contain a `char`, hence contains returns false.

The easiest approach would be to turn it to a `String`:

```
new String(arr).indexOf('4') >= 0
  // or
new String(arr).contains("4")
```

Some third-party libraries offer methods to convert a `char[]` to a `List<Character>`, for example [Chars.asList](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#asList(char...)) in Guava.

Answer (score 1):

Because for `char[]` value `Arrays.asList` method creates `List<char[]>`. If you create `Character[]` array with same values, `Arrays.asList` method will return `List<Character>`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] primitives = {'2', 'a', 'g', '4'};
    List<char[]> listOfCharArrays = Arrays.asList(primitives);
    System.out.println("4 in arr : " + listOfCharArrays.contains('4'));

    Character[] arr = {'2', 'a', 'g', '4'};
    List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(arr);
    System.out.println("4 in arr : " + chars.contains('4'));
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
4 in arr : false
4 in arr : true
```

See also:

- [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554025/want-to-create-a-stream-of-characters-from-char-array-in-java) to use a `Stream` to avoid the conversion of `arr` to `List`.  It's more verbose, but might perform better if the size of `arr` is large.

```
    char[] arr = {'2', 'a', 't', '4'};
    char search = '4';
    System.out.println(search + " in arr: " + CharBuffer.wrap(arr).chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .filter(c -> c == search)
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Character> listC = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char c : chars) {
    listC.add(c);
} 
System.out.println("4 in arr : "+listC.contains('4'));
```